# Can I get the current action that will fire in a before filter?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

In a before filter action, can I get the action that will be executed after the before filter?

Answer (score 0):

You can always access the RouteData collection(using the filter context) to check what is the action parameter.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using

```
    IActionFilter.OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
         string actionName = filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionName;
    }
```

then **filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionName** will give you the action name